# Flow Winter 23 Release HTTP Callout on Post

Tags: flowscreen

I did all the necessary steps and manage to work it via the get functionality with no issues at all.

For the post (Though it is actually on Beta) I am stuck on this specific screen:

[image]

What value is it actually referring to? I am not sure.

I am trying to Integrate it with OpenAI .

Endpoint:
https://api.openai.com/v1/completions

Sample request:

```
{
  "model": "text-davinci-003",
  "prompt": "What gifts should I buy for Christmas?",
  "max_tokens": 64,
  "temperature": 0.5
}
```

sample response:

```
 {
"id": "cmpl-7TLuEpDJ3LiAtu6li5XcOG0VBT1J4",
"object": "text_completion",
"created": 1687230074,
"model": "text-davinci-003",
"choices": [
    {
        "text": "\n\n1. Books \n2. Clothing \n3. Electronics \n4. Toys \n5. Jewelry \n6. Home Decor \n7. Gift Cards \n8. Kitchen Appliances \n9. Personalized Mugs \n10. Video Games",
        "index": 0,
        "logprobs": null,
        "finish_reason": "stop"
    }
],
"usage": {
    "prompt_tokens": 8,
    "completion_tokens": 60,
    "total_tokens": 68
}
```

}

EDIT:
Added an endpoint , request and response.

Comment: You need to generate the actual body of the request to pass into that input value. When you set up the HTTP Callout it will have generated a number of Apex classes that represent the data structures that the callout expects in the body. Within your flow you'll need to create a variable that uses those Apex Defined Data Types that you can then use as the body.

Comment: @Callum MacErlich That does not work as well as you think. One example: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/399719/external-services-accessing-nested-object-in-response

Comment: That's fair, I made an assumption on the structure of the request itself. @Snorlax would you be able to share the exact endpoint you're calling and maybe an example request structure if available?

Comment: I tried your approach and still failed. @cal

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I've finally worked out how to set the Body.

**1 - Creating the body variable**

- List item
- Create a "Body" variable which will be an Apex-Defined Variable
  (it's managed automatically in the External Services created by Salesforce).

**2 - Once you have created the "Body" variable, you need to**

- Add an Assignment component
- Add the Body variable
- Is equals to
- Create a text formula variable (used to define the content of your body)

[image: SetBody Assignment]

**3 - To process the content of the JSON response**

- Create a Text Template variable (which takes the content of the response 2XX.Data.[xxx])

At this point your JSON is interpreted as Text and you can use it in a formula or other.

**Resources** :

- Parser JSON in Flow: [Is there a way to parse Json in Flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216166/is-there-a-way-to-parse-json-in-flow)
- Unofficial SF JSON component: https://unofficialsf.com/use-datamapper-to-convert-web-json-to-salesforce-flow-objects/
- Github project Flow component : https://github.com/munawirrahman/MultipleJSONParser